# How to update an application with same installation directory with install4j

Tags: install4j

I have installed an application on system which is created with install4j. Now I am upgrade the old version of same application with new version and I want to hide the option **"No. install into different directory"** from user.

How can we avoid this option to update an application in **same installation directory** with install4j.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to hide the option "No. install into different directory" from user.

On the "Installer->Screens & Actions" step, select the "Welcome" screen in the installer and deselect the "Alert for update installation" property.

Comment: I want to show **Alert for Update Installation** but my requirement is that the previous installation directory and updated installation directory of application should be same, hence I want to hide the option "No. install into different directory" from end user.

Comment: Then you have to make such a form screen yourself using the API to detect to update condition: `context.isUpdateInstallation()`.

Comment: Sure. I appreciate your reply.